# When data changes that is passed to a Vue3 control, it doesn't update. It works when hard coded

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

This is the pared down code for the main component. I have reactive data elements setup here.

```
<template>
  <div class="scheduler">
     <recursive-render :items="data.probeGroupedData"/>
  </div>
</template>
    
<script>
import { ref } from "vue";
import RecursiveRender from "./RecursiveRender.vue";

export default {
  name: "Scheduler",
  components: {
    RecursiveRender
  },
  setup() {
    const data = ref({
      probeGroupedData: [],
      probeScriptInfo: [],
      probeScriptInfoHashById: {},
    });

    return {
      data,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    probeSort: function() {
        var result = []
        //I do various things to sort the data and fill up result and then:
        this.data.probeGroupedData = result;
        console.log("\nresult:" + JSON.stringify(result, null, '  '));
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {

    //I do various things to request the data here, and call this.probeSort
  },
};
</script>
```

The  component writes data just fine if I paste the data directly into it on setup.

```
probeGroupedData: [{
"id": "_1",
"label": "Renton, WA",
"keyName": "id",
"cssClass": "top",
"children": [
  {
    "label": "Motorola",
    "id": "_0",
    "cssClass": "manufacturer",
    "children": [
      {
        "label": "Atrix",
        "id": "_1",
        "cssClass": "family",
        "children": [
          {
            "label": "HD",
            "id": "_2",
            "cssClass": "model",
            "children": [
              {
                "isLeaf": true,
                "id": 1,
                "cssClass": "device"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }]
```

But it isn't updating it when it is being written by probeSort. Do I need to have a watcher or something know that it has changed?

This is the entire code for RecursiveRender

```
<template>
  <div>
   <div v-for="item in data.items" :class="cssClass" :key="item.id">
     <div v-if="item.isLeaf" :id="item.id">
       {{item.label}}
     </div>
     <div v-if="item.children">
        {{item.label}}
       <recursive-render :items="item.children" />
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>

</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import RecursiveRender from "./RecursiveRender.vue";

export default {
  name: 'RecursiveRender',
  components: {
    RecursiveRender
 },
 setup() {
   const data = ref({
     items: [],
   });

 return {
   data
 };
},
props: {
  items: {
    type: Array,
    default: () => []
  }
},

mounted() {
   //this is where the data is received
   this.data.items = this.items;
}
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may be due to use of `ref` instead of `reactive`

`ref` is for values like boolean, string, and number. It will not update on deep changes. If you have nested data like array or object, `reactive` might be a better option since it can look for deep data changes.

I also noticed you're not using `data.value`. `this.data.probeGroupedData = result;` is likely storing the data in the wrong place. You could try `this.data.value.probeGroupedData = result;` which may still have issues with reactivity. you could also do `this.data.value = {...this.data.value, probeGroupedData : result}` which will trigger the reactivity without worrying about the depth issue.

Comment: I just tried that, made the data reactive in both components, and still no result.

Comment: I wouldn't mix composition api with non-composition life cycle hooks, but likely they behave the same, anyway I'm not sure if class-based `onmount` handles the `this.data` differently, but I suspect you still need `.value`.

Comment: With more experience, I've learned you need to use provide / inject.

In the parent component, the data you want to have reactive needs to be provided:

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the clues that Daniel gave me. The error is passing the value on mount. Just having the prop is enough, it doesn't have to be passed back to data.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="item in items" :class="cssClass" :key="item.id">
      <div v-if="item.isLeaf" :id="item.id">
        {{item.label}}
      </div>
      <div v-if="item.children">
         {{item.label}}
        <recursive-render :items="item.children" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </template>

<script>
import RecursiveRender from "./RecursiveRender.vue";

export default {
  name: 'RecursiveRender',
  components: {
    RecursiveRender
  },
  props: {
    items: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    }
  },

};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With more experience, I've learned you need to use provide / inject.

In the parent component, the data you want to have reactive needs to be provided:

```
//add provide to the import:
import { provide, ref } from "vue";

//in setup() you need to pass this to provide:
setup() {
  const boardData = ref ({ <your data here> });
  provide('boardData', boardData);

  return {
     boardData,
     <and anything else>
  }
}
```

In the child component you need to add inject to the import:

```
import { ref, inject } from "vue";
```

In setup you inject it using the same name as you used to provide it:

```
setup() {

  const boardData = inject('boardData');

  return {
     boardData,
     //and whatever else you need for the component
  }
}
```

This is being used now for a backgammon game that has child pips, and it works well. For layout reasons the pips need to be in four groups of six, so I used a child component for them so I didn't have to have complex repeated loops in the main code. The pips now behave as they are all on rendered in the parent, and changes that the pips do to the reactive data are rendered properly in other sets of pips.